# Designing object oriented synchronous receiver and transmitter

Tags: c++, c, oop, sockets, protocols

I'm working on a project for a data communications class that is a synchronous transmitter and receiver. The transmitter will be the server using sockets and when receiver client connects it will fork and send a message to the receiver that is is stored in a text file given as an argument on server startup.

My question is not implementation, I know how to implement all this functionality. My question is how to organize this into classes etc in C++.

The messages will be 2 SYN characters, a control character indicating length of message, and up to 64 bytes of message data.

My first thought automatically is that I want a server class and a client class. I will have 2 main functions, one will have a server(transmitter) object, the other will have a client (receiver) object. Moving up from these highest level classes I don't know how to organize the lower level stuff.

I need a distinct "physical", "data link", and "application" layers. Physical layer will handle converting message to binary, calculating parity, etc. data link layer will frame the messages, and the application will be the highest level. How to organize these? Namespaces?

Like I said, implementation is not my problem. Just design, I often get frustrated because I feel we aren't taught enough on the design and organization of things. C++ is my area of expertise, C is fine also, I just have zero experience doing advanced applications without classes and the such.

Feel free to recommend reading in the classic Design Patterns book as I have a copy of that. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Why is this tagged 'C'?

Comment: I suggest a `Message` class that can handle its own serialization/deserialization. Why do you need three distinct layers?

Comment: I agree the three distinct layers seems overkill here. I need them because the project description says I do. Thats why I thought something as simple as namespaces may satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My tip would be that you have a "message" class used by both the client and the server.  That class would encapsulate the networking onion layers.  Since you want to both send and receive messages, you would either have two constructors -- one for assembling a message to send based on parameters, and one for parsing a raw stream of input into a message received -- or else a pure virtual base for two derived classes.

Do not be tempted to reference the server or client class in the message class; make the coupling one way such that the server/client classes use message objects.

Also use a pure virtual base for the server/client classes, representing an interface to a socket.  **Presuming TCP:** This would also be the basis of the connections maintained by the server, since each connection is a separate socket.  The socket at the heart of the server is a `listen()` socket and does not need to do any reading or writing, it just `accept()`s, but when it does it creates a new connection object whose socket will be read and written to, so those are routines that can be wrapped by the base class.  To summarize:

```
abstract class "TCPsocket" 
    -> derived class "Server"
    -> derived class "Client"
    -> derived class "Connection"
```

A Server object would contain a varying number of active Connection objects; a Client object would just be a Client object.

Comment: By pure virtual base do you mean an abstract class with all pure virtual functions?

Comment: Not necessarily *all*.  A "pure virtual", aka. "abstract" class in C++ has at least *one* pure virtual method and therefore cannot be instantiated; it just serves as a base class.  I suppose the ones here need not be literally that...my point was just that such a base "message" class would not be intended for instantiation.  Note that even if the class cannot be instantiated (because it really is abstract), you can pass an object around with that type and use it -- but you would need to create it using a non-abstract derived class.  This is an important potential of *polymorphism* in OOP.

Comment: The idea is that all the code that is usable in both a "messageIn" and "messageOut" object would be in the base "message" class, same goes for the "client" and "server" in relation to a "socket".  It may be that it makes more sense to just use a single message class with two different constructors, as mentioned.

Comment: But maybe a "Stream" class that both the server and client inherit from? The stream class could contain the socket as you mentioned.

Comment: Sure.  Having done something like this before, there probably isn't a huge amount of stuff in that base class specific to handling the socket, but it is nice to start out with, since one such object will be at the core of the independent server and client processes.  You can then use that same base to implement things like logging for both processes.  I've fleshed out a relationship to a third class, representing connections to clients made by the server, above (which if you fork,  those are separate processes too).